# Shoulda validation for multiple attributes on one line?

Tags: ruby, shoulda

With the older Shoulda plugin I was using, I used to be able to do something like the following:

```
should_have_many :posts, :authors, :comments
```

After upgrading my version of Shoulda, I had to change it to something like this:

```
should have_many :posts
should have_many :authors
should have_many :comments
```

I've tried putting it all on one line so it's just

```
should have_many :posts, :authors, :comments
```

but that's not working. Is there anyway to DRY this up a little?

I'm using Shoulda 2.11.3

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
[:posts, :authors, :comments].each do |models|
  it { should have_many(models) }
end
```

This will show up in the results as three separate tests.

I use Rspec, so above is Rspec formatting, but I assume a similar approach should work with Test::Unit.

I'm not sure if this is going to save you all that much but if you have many of the same type of relationship it would become more valuable. Perhaps it is of better use for `allow_mass_assignment_of`.

Comment: Maybe it will be faster:

`it{ [:posts, :authors, :comments].each{ |models|
  should have_many(models) } }`

cause will perform as single test. But in this case You'll see only last successful message from Shoulda.

Also there is a [Remarkable ActiveRecord gem](https://github.com/remarkable/remarkable-activerecord).